# Start DataGridView with empty editable table

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to start a `DataGridview` totally empty and ready for user input in the first cell. I tried creating a `Datatable` with a unused column, add a new row with only a value in that column and hide it, but then the `DataGridview` shows me two rows:

[image]

How can I start with only one empty row?

Code for `Datatable`:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Nummer");
dt.Columns.Add("Unternummer");
dt.Columns.Add("Betrag");
dt.Columns.Add("Datum");

dt.Rows.Add("", "", "", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
gv_Input.DataSource = dt;
```

Hide the column and make first cell ready for input:

```
private void gv_Input_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    gv_Input.Columns[3].Visible = false;
    DataGridViewCell cell = gv_Input.Rows[0].Cells[0];
    gv_Input.CurrentCell = cell;
    gv_Input.BeginEdit(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the [`AllowUserToAddRows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows(v=vs.110).aspx) property of your `DataGridView` to `False`. Like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
...
...
gv_Input.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Just another question, how can I access this first row? `gv_input.Rows` returns me 0 (zero)?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `AllowUserToAddRows` property to `true` you do not need to add a Row to the DataTable.

```
//dt.Rows.Add("", "", "", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
```

Comment: Thanks but then the editing `gv_Input.BeginEdit(true);` is no longer possible